# Values messed up when pushing Multi level Object Literal to array

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, multidimensional-array, literals

**I've got a json object with multiple levels, let's call it ZOO.**

```
var ZOO = {
            info: {
                cages: {
                    amount: 5,
                    size: { x: 1, y: 0.2 },
                    additionals: 'a broken bucket',
                },
            },
        }, myZoos = [];
```

**Now i want to clone & alter this object then add it to an array called myZoos.**

```
window.JSON.clone = function (json) {
    return $.extend({}, json);
};
for (var a = 1; a <= 3; a++) {
            var newZoo = JSON.clone(ZOO);
            newZoo.info.cages.size = { x: (a * 5), y: (a * 2) };
            myZoos.push(newZoo);
        }
```

**Let's read our filled array and check the random size values!**

```
for (var b = 0; b < myZoos.length; b++) {
            var myZoo = myZoos[b];
            console.log(myZoo.info.cages.size);
        }
```

**Result:**

```
Object { x: 15, y: 6 }
Object { x: 15, y: 6 }
Object { x: 15, y: 6 }
```

Looks like i'm only getting the last value that was pushed to the array!
Why is only the last item in the array returned?

Comment: Where does `JSON.clone` come from and how does it work? FYI, that's not JSON at all, that's a **JavaScript object literal** (creating an object when evaluated).

Comment: @FelixKling - OP is defining `JSON.clone()` in the second code fragment.

Comment: window.JSON.clone above the first for loop, i'll change the tags / title.

Comment: You are only doing a *shallow* copy of the value, see the documentation of `$.extend` for doing a *deep* copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the deep-copy parameter of the [`.extend()` method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/#jQuery-extend-deep-target-object1-objectN)

```
window.JSON.clone = function (json) {
    return $.extend(true, {}, json);
};
```

Comment: THANKS! That was the mistake i couldn't find!